# centering subviews in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIView in which inside of that I have a UIImageView and a UILabel and a UIButton. Sometimes the UIbutton is present/seen and sometimes not, sometimes the UIImageView is seen and sometimes not. What is the best way to adjust this view so that whatever is seen is always centered in this UIView? I've tried setting the autoresizeFrameWidth but it didnt work.

Comment: whenever you are going to show `UIButton` or `UIImageView` or `UILabel`make `uibutton.center=uiview.center;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to follow what you really want. I think your question needs to be more specific. Are you using the Interface Builder and using the Autosizing features? Are you locking all sides?

If you are still having trouble, then the layoutSubviews approach already mentioned by sch is the way forward. Either use .center property or calculate the center from the bounds of the superview.